# Using of deeply nested pointers

Tags: c, performance

Suppose we have to use in some function deeply nested pointer very extensively:

```
function (ptr_a_t ptr_a) {
    ...
    a = ptr_a->ptr_b->ptr_c->val;
    b = ptr_a->ptr_b->ptr_c->val;
    ...
}
```

Assuming all pointers are checked and valid, is there performance degradation, problems with atomicity or other caveats (except readability) in comparison with:

```
function (ptr_a_t ptr_a) {
    val = ptr_a->ptr_b->ptr_c->val;
    ...
    a = val;
    b = val;
    ...
}
```

**Update**
I compiled this c file (written only for investigation purposes) with gcc -S:

```
typedef struct {
  int val;
} c_str_t;

typedef struct {
  c_str_t *p_c;     
} b_str_t;

typedef struct {
  b_str_t *p_b;     
} a_str_t;

void func (a_str_t *p_a) 
{
     int a,b;

     a = p_a->p_b->p_c->val;
     b = p_a->p_b->p_c->val;

     printf("", a,b);
}
```

**For gcc -S:**

```
movl    8(%ebp), %eax
movl    (%eax), %eax
movl    (%eax), %eax
movl    (%eax), %eax
movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)
movl    8(%ebp), %eax
movl    (%eax), %eax
movl    (%eax), %eax
movl    (%eax), %eax
movl    %eax, -8(%ebp)
```

**For gcc -S -O1:**

```
movl    8(%ebp), %eax
movl    (%eax), %eax
movl    (%eax), %eax
movl    (%eax), %eax
movl    %eax, 8(%esp)
movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
```

The same I observe using *volatile* specificator inside structures.
So, nested pointers are forcedly optimized.

Comment: Another option:a = b = ptr_a->ptr_b->ptr_c->val;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether these will be treated as the same is implementation-dependent.  Compile your code both ways and examine the assembly output to see how your compiler treats both cases.

On an embedded system I am developing for, I added an "intermediate" pointer like you did and saw an appreciable speed-up in the execution time of the function.  In my case, the compiler was re-calculating the pointer chain from scratch each time and was not optimizing them down.  Your compiler may be different, the only real way to tell is to try it both ways and measure the execution time.

Comment: You're right. Without optimization, gcc recalculates pointers. See my update.

Answer (score 3):

Unless some of those intermediate struct members are marked *volatile*, the compiler should treat your two examples as equivalent.  I would prefer your second code sample just because it looks cleaner.

Comment: Note that it says *should* treat them as equivalent.  There is no rule that says this must or must not happen, it is dependent on the particular compiler (and possibly on the optimization options used).

Comment: How optimizer can now whether one of the pointers is not changed (due to scheduler) between two lines in the first case?.

Comment: @Pmod: unless something is marked "volatile", the compiler can assume that a variable doesn't spontaeously change in the middle of a function.

Comment: If your program uses shared-memory concurrency and, say, "ptr_b" can change between program statements, the program has a non-deterministic bug in it.

Comment: this also gets into locking, if you do your locking correctly the result is the same (in particular if you need to lock the top level struct the compiler will not move dereferences to before the lock) this is part of the whole 'correctly locked programs are sequentially consistent' thing

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure your compiler will optimize the two to the same code as gcc does.

You can check this very easily by generating the assembler code for both (in gcc use the -S switch) and compare them.